# Improve gaussian filter + thresholding

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm working on a set of pictures for a physics experience: https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=f08936bf-074d-07e1-a2f7-5c93cf74c194

In the folder, there are 3 image sets. For each of them we have a lot of pictures taken every millisecond, and on each pic we have 4 black points on a white background. 
My aim is to get a plot by measuring the deformation between the upper point and the flatter point, and the deformation from the left to the right.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from skimage import filters
from skimage import measure
from operator import itemgetter
import glob

plt.interactive(False)


def trouve(titre):
    #Extract time in the image title
    local_tiretbas = titre.rfind('_')+1
    local_tiff = titre.find('.tiff')
    return float(titre[local_tiretbas:local_tiff])


array_results = []

image_list = sorted(glob.glob('/home/nicolas/PycharmProjects/Imagerie/14/t1_ep_p/*.tiff'), key=trouve)

T = [] #TimeList
for i in range(len(image_list)):
   T.append(trouve(image_list[i]))
   picture = plt.imread(image_list[i])
   cutout = picture[900:1150, int(350 + i*2.8):int(650 + 3.2*i)]
   cutout_improved = filters.gaussian(cutout, sigma=3)
   val = filters.threshold_otsu(cutout_improved)
   mask = cutout_improved < val
   mask_filled = scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes(mask)
   I_label = measure.label(mask_filled,background=0)
   region_properties = measure.regionprops(I_label)


   l = []
for label in region_properties:
    centroid = label.centroid
    l.append(centroid)  
tuple_values = (max(l, key=itemgetter(1))[1]-min(l, key=itemgetter(1))[1], max(l, key=itemgetter(0))[0]-min(l, key=itemgetter(0))[0])
array_results.append(tuple_values)
l0 = array_results[0][0]
h0 = array_results[0][1]
DL = [i[0]/l0 for i in array_results]
DT = [i[1]/h0 for i in array_results]
plt.plot(T, DL, label='Déplacement longitudinal', color='green')
plt.plot(T, DT, label='Déplacement transversal', color='red')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

The best result I succeed in getting is this image for one dataset. This is not perfect but this is cool. However for the two left this code doesn't work, and I'm looking for some tips to locate the black points. 
SO far I have only used skimage but I'm also likely to use openCV if it works better.

[Here is the best result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ossJv.png)

[Here is the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpFRP.png)

If you have any idea to help me out with this gaussian filter and the thresholding, feel free ! 
I have already tried a canny edge detection but it wasn't a great success unfortunately.

Best regards,
Nicolas.

Comment: Your images link appears to have expired.

Comment: At any rate I suggest that you step through your functions for the images before and after the discontinuities you're observing. Clearly something changes at those points and you need to account for that in your function.